# load font permanently

Tags: macos, fonts, customization, core-text, custom-font

I am building a mac application that needs to use an custom font. The font is loaded using `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` function. The font was loaded every time the application  started running.

Is there anyway just to load the font once, and simply use it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `kCTFontManagerScopeUser` parameter to `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` function, will make the font available in subsequent sessions.